# Batch is inserting only one record in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I have this code using DataStax Java Driver

```
            PreparedStatement pstmt = cqlSession.prepare("INSERT INTO ks_mobapp.messages(pair_id, date, belong_to, message_id, text, sender) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
            BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(pstmt);
            BatchStatement batchStmt = new BatchStatement();
            batchStmt.add(boundStatement.bind(pair, formatDate, pairSplit[0], obj.getLong("time"), text, sndrId));
            batchStmt.add(boundStatement.bind(pair, formatDate, pairSplit[1], obj.getLong("time"), text, sndrId));
            cqlSession.execute(batchStmt);
```

Here `pairSplit[0]` & `pairSplit[1]` are different but at the end only one line is inserting.

Her is my table

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    pair_id text,
    date text,
    message_id bigint,
    text text,
    sender text,
    belong_to text,
    PRIMARY KEY((pair_id, date, belong_to), message_id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked at their sample demos. I think you need two different **BoundStatement** objects.

Without that, I am afraid, you may have ended up passing the same reference twice. This is the usual way of things work in java (We avoid deep copying objects).

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the same BoundStatement. This will work:

```
        PreparedStatement pstmt = cqlSession.prepare("INSERT INTO ks_mobapp.messages(pair_id, date, belong_to, message_id, text, sender) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
        BatchStatement batchStmt = new BatchStatement();
        batchStmt.add(new BoundStatement(pstmt).bind(pair, formatDate, pairSplit[0], obj.getLong("time"), text, sndrId));
        batchStmt.add(new BoundStatement(pstmt).bind(pair, formatDate, pairSplit[1], obj.getLong("time"), text, sndrId));
        cqlSession.execute(batchStmt);
```

Regards